# Categorizing Gmail messages based on the time user spent reading the message

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am looking for the following feature in Gmail.

For each message I open, it tracks the time I spent reading the message when it is feasible to do so. For example, if I open message 1 and then move to message 2, by clicking a button within 2 seconds, it notes that the time spent on message 1 is less than 2 seconds.

Gmail automatically labels the messages on which the User spends less than some configurable amount of time (say 2 seconds) and assigns them a label, say "LowAttentionSpan". This way the user can periodically look for messages with this label and take actions like unsubscribing from a list to minimize the amount of time spent on the Inbox.

Is such a feature already available now or can it be developed using Gmail API?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this feature is not yet available for Gmail. Referencing the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels), there are no such labels similar to what you are looking for nor can you customize to have such labels.

Answer (score 2):

As gerardnimo said, there is currently no such feature available for Gmail. An approximate solution using the Gmail API comes to mind though:

1. [Subscribe to push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) and issue a [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) on the `UNREAD`-label.
2. Every time you get a push notification related to a certain user, it will mean that the user just started reading a mail (or marked an old mail as `UNREAD`). Check the difference in time since last time you got a notification for the same user. If the difference was less than `LowAttentionSpan` seconds, you could add a [custom label to it](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/modify).

This simple solution has some caveats though.

If the user marks an old message as unread, it might cause some unwanted behavior.

Also, if the user reads only one mail, and comes back e.g. three hours later to read another one, the solution above will interpret that as the user read the first mail for three hours, which will not be the case. It will in other words just work when the user reads multiple new mails in succession.