# Gmail API - Adding an attribute for each mail. Is it possible?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Let's suppose I want to create a tracking time web app and one of the features allows the user to track the time spent sending mails. So, when receiving or sending an email, there would be an option for indicating how long it took the user to send or read that email. Then, from the website of my web app (mytrackingtimeapp.com), the users could create custom charts and reports for listing, for example, all the emails that took him more than 10 minutes to read and were sent in June.

If I had in a database of mine all the emails, this would be as simple as create a column for each email storing that value.

So my question is: **would it be possible with the current Gmail API do so?**

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428539/categorizing-gmail-messages-based-on-the-time-user-spent-reading-the-message?rq=1) that is related to your question.

Comment: @KENdi thank you. That helped me out :)